# How to style this value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to apply this style with jQuery so that it has wider support than just applying it via css.

It is involving the calc() function of CSS3.

Here is the CSS3 style:

```
#search{
    top:calc(3rem + 32px);
}
```

How can I add the 32px when applying this style in jQuery. Is there a way I can do mathematical operations in jQuery?

Here is what I know how to do right now, with a single unit:

```
$('#search').css('top','3rem');
```

Can I do something like:

```
$('#search').css('top','3rem + 32px');
```

If so, how?

Comment: Did you try `.css('top','calc(3rem + 32px)');`

Comment: @adeneo that works, but it is still dependent on calc() support. Is there a way I can do the addition in javascript / jquery?

Comment: You can chain calls of `css`: `$("#search").css('top', '3rem').css('top', '+=32px');`

Comment: Well, browsers that don't support `calc()` generally don't support `rem` units either ?

Comment: @adeneo I know, but I have a different fallback for rem units failing. I don't have one for calc() failing.

Comment: Then post the fallback for rem units, as calculating rem and pixels with javascript when calc() fails has no meaning, as rem won't be supported anyway ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I add the 32px when applying this style in jQuery. Is there a way I can do mathematical operations in jQuery?

Try this:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tvqfn/)

```
$('#search').css("top","3rem").css("top", "+=32px")
```

Calc is not supported in all browser see for [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcalc). But this at least is guaranteed to work.

As @adeneo pointed out look at the support for [rem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Flength)

Comment: People will upvote anything? Look at the support for [calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc), then look at the support for [rem units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem), and notice that calc() is supported in a lot more browsers than rem, so in browsers that don't support rem units, this won't work, and that's pretty much the same as calc() ?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for pointing that out. well my answer was more towards his specific question.But i was not aware of `rem` support.

Comment: It's a neat answer, chaining to add 32px to the already set value, but the question was to calculate in jQuery to gain wider browser support, so using calc() would'nt be neccessary, and setting values in jQuery with rem units has poorer support than calc(), so doing this does'nt really make much sense in my opinion, but other than just answering that what the OP is trying to do makes no sense, this is probably the next best thing ?